# ピクセルパーフェクトの正しいやり方がわかりません。

Tags: html, css

ウェブデザイナー(コーディングもできる)を目指しています。

ピクセルパーフェクトが重要だと聞き、やり方を調べると、
XDやフォトショップの見本のデザインをスクショで撮り、拡張機能のパーフェクトピクセル、で当てはめて調節するやり方と、
XDやフォトショップの数値通りにデザインするだけでもピクセルパーフェクトというようだとわかりました。

どっちがほんとうのピクセルパーフェクトのやり方なのでしょうか？

プロのウェブデザイナーまたはコーダーの方は、どのようにピクセルパーフェクトをやってますか？

Comment: 何が正しいは非常に難しい問題のような気がします。「ピクセルパーフェクト」の定義もプロダクトやプロジェクトに依ってくる印象です。私の経験則では「ピクセルパーフェクト」自体そこまで重要視されていないです。デザイナーもXDの表現とHTMLの表現の違いには限界があることを理解しているので、ある程度折り合いをつけてスピード重視で開発することが多いですね。もちろんスキルとしては重要なのでぜひ高めてもらえればとは思います。

Comment: お答えいただきありがとうございます。ちなみに、回答者様は、XDやフォトショップでサイズを図ってそれをそのまま打ち込む形で行うのでしょうか？他には何かしますか？

Comment: 残念ながらこのSOでは、アンケート形式や一意に回答が定まらない質問は[オフトピック](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)として扱われますので回答は差し控えさせていただきます。

Comment: 承知しました、ご検討くださり、ありがとうございました。